# Why do I need to add nameservers to resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from some earlier version) which uses Network Manager and systemd-resolved for name resolution. When I boot, my ethernet connection `enp0s31f6` is brought up by Network Manager and given three nameserver addresses via DHCP, `10.1.13.10`, `10.1.141.10`, `10.1.13.36`. Running `nmcli` shows the three nameservers under "DNS configuration". Running `systemd-resolve --status` shows them under a "Link 2 (enp0s31f6)" section. I can ping each one. No other connection is active.

```
testuser ☼ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNS Domain: (my org's domain)
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (wlp4s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.1.13.10
                      10.1.141.10
                      10.1.13.36
          DNS Domain: (my org's domain)
```

However, when I actually try to resolve a name, even the name of one of the nameservers, `dig` claims that "connection timed out: no servers could be reached".

```
testuser ☼ dig dcpdc001.(my org's domain)

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> dcpdc001.(my org's domain)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Note that this name should resolve to `10.1.13.10`, the first nameserver.

I have configured `resolvconf` to use dynamic updates. `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. This file contains only (non-comments):

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search (my orgs local search domain)
```

If I add `nameserver 10.1.13.10` to this file manually, suddenly `dig` can resolve again, and anything else that needs to see local names can do so. Removing the nameserver breaks that again.

I don't know much about the servers. They're part of a Windows-based network, but I can use them if I edit `resolv.conf` manually so I don't think that's the issue, and it implies I don't need to be authenticated to the domain to use them. (I can authenticate to the domain via Ubuntu using Realmd/SSSD, but not if I can't resolve the domain controller...)

The `journalctl` entries for `systemd-resolved` show only a few messages about "Using degraded feature set ... for DNS server" but they only refer to the third nameserver, not the others. Nothing for the primary nameserver.

How can I get name resolution working without having to manually edit `resolv.conf` every time I boot?

I assume the contents of my `resolv.conf` mean that Network Manager or Systemd has some sort of local caching resolver running? If so, would bypassing it fix things?

---

I increased the logging level of `systemd-resolved` and `journalctl -f -u systemd-resolved` shows:

```
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Got DNS stub UDP query packet for id 19836
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Looking up RR for dcpdc001.(org domain) IN A.
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Switching to DNS server 10.1.13.10 for interface enp0s31f6.
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Cache miss for dcpdc001.(org domain) IN A
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Transaction 12728 for <dcpdc001.(org domain) IN A> scope dns on enp0s31f6/*.
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0+DO+LARGE for transaction 12728.
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Using DNS server 10.1.13.10 for transaction 12728.
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Sending query packet with id 12728.
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Processing query...
Jul 20 10:33:23 heerij-ubuntu systemd-resolved[2352]: Timeout reached on transaction 12728.
```

Comment: [Bug report submitted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1782679).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80472/discussion-on-question-by-detly-why-do-i-need-to-add-nameservers-to-resolv-conf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Systemd comes with a "stub" resolver, systemd-resolved, which according to them is [not actually meant to be used as a DNS server](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4621#issuecomment-260050033):

> Well, resolved is not supposed to be a DNS server, it's supposed to be exactly good enough so that libc-like DNS clients can resolve their stuff, and we carry enough info for the AD bit to be set.

For whatever reason, Ubuntu is configured to use it as a DNS server and, in fact, the only one.

A [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320/comments/8) on [bug #1624320](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320) points out that systemd-resolved has three modes of operation, and the second one is what fixed my problem. Namely:

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This is actually good to know since I will be upgrading to 18.04 soon and I was worried about it resolving to 127.0.0.53 instead of my DNS server.  Better control in my opinion.  +1

Comment: @Terrance Glad we got to the bottom of it then!

Comment: It's worth noting for Google searches that this resolve a DNS resolution problem I had on AWS, where my Ubuntu 18.04 image couldn't resolve Route53 entries.

Comment: Also fixed my Comcast imap mail server resolution problem. Thanks!