# DNS/systemd-resolve/dnsmasq/resolvconf problems. Errors in syslog. 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dns, resolvconf

I'm trying to resolve these two repeating errors in `/var/log/syslog`...

```
nf_conntrack: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet

Maximum number of concurrent DNS queries reached (max: 150)
```

Looking at `/etc/resolv.conf`...

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I know that the nameserver should be 127.0.0.53, from looking at my other 18.04 system. If I manually change (which I know I shouldn't do) 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.53, the errors **seem** to stop in syslog. Of course, a reboot sets this file back to 127.0.0.1.

How do I get resolv.conf to correctly show 127.0.0.53, and survive reboots? Am I barking up the right tree?

Comment: Maybe this might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1057752/231142

Comment: @Terrance thanks for the possible lead... however, implementing the symlink change of /etc/resolv.conf didn't fix the error messages, and now dnsmasq generated error messages 'cause it noticed the symlink wasn't pointing at the "right" place any more.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't know yet.  This Netplan seems different.  However, I do know for me I don't like using netmasq.  If ever I can make it so it uses my DNS server and not the built in one I get better results.  I should be upgrading to 18.04 next week possibly then I might know more.

Comment: @Terrance and the really confusing part is knowing the relationship between systemd-resolve and dnsmasq and resolveconf... who gets the DNS query first, what do they do with it, and who/how do they pass it off to the next app?

Comment: You probably have dnsmasq stepping on the toes of systemd-revolved, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved, the answers there may help.

Comment: @BernardWei thanks for the possible lead. It's a little complicated, and I don't know if starting systemd-resolve after dnsmasq will work... but I'll have to spend more time analyzing my situation. I'd still like to know why one 18.04 system shows 127.0.0.53 in /etc/resolv.conf, and another system shows 127.0.0.1. And who's generating all of the DNS queries.

Comment: @Terrance FYI, you may wish to look at my answer, so when you upgrade to 18.04, you'll know what to do if you have the same problem as I did.

Comment: @BernardWei Your link gave me enough information to help me solve the problem. Please see my answer. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, thanks to @Terrance and @BernardWei for pointing me to information that ultimately helped me resolve this problem. I used parts of their links to formulate my own process to resolve the repeating error messages in syslog.

Looking at `/etc/resolv.conf` gives a clue. The nameserver is 127.0.0.1, and that is placed there by dnsmasq. In 18.04 it should be 127.0.0.53, placed there by systemd-resolved.

On my system, I did:

```
ps auxc | grep -i dns
ps auxc | grep -i resolv
```

And found that both dnsmasq and systemd-resolved were running, and as far as DNS is concerned, they overlap in functionality. There are two possible fixes.

Fix #1:

I uninstalled dnsmasq and dnsmasq-base *(probably left over from a system prior to -29)*, and then restarted systemd-resolved. `/etc/resolv.conf` now correctly shows that the nameserver is 127.0.0.53.

Fix #2:

If you need BOTH dnsmasq and systemd-resolved running, then edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

and restart systemd-resolved.

Comment: Glad you found a way, good to know about Fix #2, cheers.

Comment: @heynnema I have exactly the same problem but need dnsmasq as it selves as DHCP and DNS for a WiFiHotspot running on the same machine. When setting DNSStubListener=no the flooding between 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.53 stops, but unfortunately my docker containers also stop working ....

Comment: @f0rd42 what is in your /etc/resolv.conf? Did you restart both dnsmasq and systemd-resolved?

Comment: @heynnema I have given up on 18.04. Installed 16.04 and have everything working in 2% of the time I spend on 18.04 for troubleshooting :-)