# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 - DNS name resolution not working

Tags: 18.04, dns, display-resolution

I have a VM running Ubuntu 18.04, been working fine, but recently found I cannot update the server. Seems to be a DNS name resolution issue.

I have confirmed that DNS is working correctly, and there are not firewalls prohibiting correct name res.

I've seen some mention of name resolution bugs, but clearly as I cannot perform name resolution, I cannot update the server. Any help?

Original error with Apt update:

```
user001@server001:~$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host server001: Resource temporarily unavailable
[sudo] password for user001:
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'download.docker.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.docker.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Name Resolution failing:

```
user001@server001:~$ ping google.co.uk
ping: google.co.uk: Temporary failure in name resolution
user001@server001:~$
```

NSLookup against same server works fine:

```
user001@server001:~$ nslookup
> server 192.168.0.201
Default server: 192.168.0.201
Address: 192.168.0.201#53
> google.co.uk
Server:         192.168.0.201
Address:        192.168.0.201#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.co.uk
Address: 172.217.169.3
Name:   google.co.uk
Address: 2a00:1450:4009:818::2003
> exit
```

Systemd-resolve output:

```
user001@server001:~$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens160)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.201
                      192.168.0.1
```

Couple of extra points. I am using Netplan and IP information is assigned through DHCP.  All of this is default out of the box. 
The server is used to run docker for dev.

Anyone able to suggest next steps?

Thanks

Comment: I had DNS problems with Thunderbird in 18.04, this answer fixed it for me. https://askubuntu.com/a/1057752/243321

Comment: I tried the above, neither of which work for me. Still having the same problem. see below;    `user001@server001:/etc# sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo: unable to resolve host server001: Resource temporarily unavailable` and `user001@server001:/etc# sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo: unable to resolve host server001: Resource temporarily unavailable` Neither resolves the above behaviour.

Comment: @nmpuk could you edit question and add contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and list of installed `libnss-*` libs.